# How do I select or group multiple rows under a header row in pandas / python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .txt file from a barcode scanner that scans room IDs as well as equipment barcodes. The room ID/barcodes are scanned first, then all the equipment inside of the room is scanned after, then a new room is scanned, etc. I want to group the equipment barcodes under each room ID. The file does not contain header rows by default.

From pd.read_csv:

[date, time, (?), Room or Equipment ID]

```
0 13/12/2022,08:01:34,01,XY1110122
1 13/12/2022,08:02:59,01,Z10001234
2 13/12/2022,08:04:04,01,Z10001235
3 13/12/2022,08:48:05,01,Z10001236
4 13/12/2022,09:47:57,01,XY1110123
5 13/12/2022,09:48:15,01,Z10001237
6 13/12/2022,09:48:20,01,Z10001238
7 13/12/2022,09:48:22,01,Z10001239
```

Ideally, my output would look like this:

```
0 Equipment ID Room ID
1 Z10001234 XY1110122
2 Z10001235 XY1110122
3 Z10001236 XY1110122
4 Z10001237 XY1110123
5 Z10001238 XY1110123
6 Z10001239 XY1110123
```

I can't seem to find anything in the pandas documentation or online, but I am extremely new to pandas and python in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = [['13/12/2022', '08:01:34', 1, 'XY1110122'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '08:02:59', 1, 'Z10001234'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '08:04:04', 1, 'Z10001235'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '08:48:05', 1, 'Z10001236'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '09:47:57', 1, 'XY1110123'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '09:48:15', 1, 'Z10001237'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '09:48:20', 1, 'Z10001238'], 
        ['13/12/2022', '09:48:22', 1, 'Z10001239']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

`df`

```
    col1        col2    col3    col4
0   13/12/2022  08:01:34    1   XY1110122
1   13/12/2022  08:02:59    1   Z10001234
2   13/12/2022  08:04:04    1   Z10001235
3   13/12/2022  08:48:05    1   Z10001236
4   13/12/2022  09:47:57    1   XY1110123
5   13/12/2022  09:48:15    1   Z10001237
6   13/12/2022  09:48:20    1   Z10001238
7   13/12/2022  09:48:22    1   Z10001239
```

---

**Code**

```
cond1 = df['col4'].str.startswith('XY')
cols = ['Equipment ID', 'Room ID']
result = pd.concat([df['col4'], df['col4'].where(cond1).ffill()], axis=1, keys=cols)[~cond1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

`result`:

```
    Equipment ID    Room ID
0   Z10001234   XY1110122
1   Z10001235   XY1110122
2   Z10001236   XY1110122
3   Z10001237   XY1110123
4   Z10001238   XY1110123
5   Z10001239   XY1110123
```